# Adobe AEM 6.4.x workflows: graniteWorkItem is undefined when used in an OR split

Tags: aem, aem-6

I'm trying to run a script in an OR split and I keep on getting the error below. According to this [page](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/workflows-customizing-extending.html), "graniteWorkItem" is included in the list of "variables that are immediately available to process scripts, providing access to objects of the workflow Java API" (quoted from the link).

observations:

- I tried "workItem" which I believe is the variable for CQ5? same error.
- I removed the OR Split and then inserted a dynamic participant step. On the participant chooser, I selected Workflow Initiator Participant Chooser (Script). I then used the code below and ticked "email". I tried both "workItem" and "graniteWorkItem" variable names. I ran the workflow under my other acct and using both variable names, I got an email and no errors in error.log

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

---

**OR split script (with error. see below)**

```
function check() {  
    var workflowData = graniteWorkItem.getWorkflowData();
     return false;  
}
```

**dynamic participant script (no error with graniteWorkItem in the error.log)**

```
function getParticipant() {
    return graniteWorkItem.getWorkflow().getInitiator();
}
```

**error from error.log**

```
> tail -f error.log | grep -i "graniteWorkItem"
    var workflowData = graniteWorkItem.getWorkflowData();
} : Failure running script /libs/workflow/scripts/dynamic.ecma: ReferenceError: "graniteWorkItem" is not defined. (NO_SCRIPT_NAME#2)
org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: Failure running script /libs/workflow/scripts/dynamic.ecma: ReferenceError: "graniteWorkItem" is not defined. (NO_SCRIPT_NAME#2)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "graniteWorkItem" is not defined. (NO_SCRIPT_NAME#2)
    var workflowData = graniteWorkItem.getWorkflowData();
com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowException: org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: Failure running script /libs/workflow/scripts/dynamic.ecma: ReferenceError: "graniteWorkItem" is not defined. (NO_SCRIPT_NAME#2)
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: Failure running script /libs/workflow/scripts/dynamic.ecma: ReferenceError: "graniteWorkItem" is not defined. (NO_SCRIPT_NAME#2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a 100% sure, but isn't workflowData available in the check() method anyway - without taking it from a work item?

Comment: I have to check but workflowData is definitely NOT in the list of variables. Even the example in the page I linked derives workflowData from graniteWorkItem

Comment: Yes I know. But all the examples I found (in my local vanilla AEM instance) for function check() do directly access workflowData.

Comment: Where did you find the examples? Which built-in workflow? Thanks